# How do I add/remove a hasMany relationship for a Model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So lets say I have two models: **User** and **Book**.

**User**

```
var User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    books: DS.hasMany('book')
});
```

**Book**

```
var Book = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('user')
})
```

So I want to be able to "checkout" and return books for a certain user. Given the following **BookController**, whats the best practice for removing and adding the relationship without actually deleting the book?

```
var BookController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['userProfile'],
    actions: {
        checkOutBook: function(){
            var currentBook = this.get('model');
            var userBooks = this.get('controllers.userProfile.model.books');
            //add relationship to user
        },
        returnBook: function() {
            var currentBook = this.get('model');
            var userBooks = this.get('controllers.userProfile.model.books');
            //remove relationship to user
        }
    }
})
```

using `Ember 1.5.1` and`Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a`

Answer (score 0):

```
//add
userBooks.pushObject(currentBook);

//remove
userBooks.removeObject(currentBook)
```